# Excel out of memory warning when importing text files with VBA

Tags: excel, out-of-memory, vba

When importing multiple txt files via VBA into Excel I run into the an out of memory warning related to `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`. At exactly 723 properly imported text files the error pops up.

This is the VBA code I use:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim myfiles
Dim i As Integer

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)
     With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
        .Name = "Sample"
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next i
Else
MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this has to do with the cache size, page size and records per page. If you try the following code
objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM " & CSV_FILE, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

```
If Not objRecordset.EOF Then
intpagecount = objRecordset.PageCount
MsgBox intpagecount
MsgBox objRecordset.PageSize
Debug.Print objRecordset.CacheSize
```

end if

on a large CSV file, you'll find that VBA always shows a Memory Full error at the end of each page. In this case, there are 10 records per page, and 50585 pages.  Sure enough, I get a memory full at each page 10*50585 = 505850 records.

Answer (score 0):

You may have lots of connections in the workbook as you keep adding them but not deleting them afterwards.

Try this but run `Sub CleanUpQT()` first as a one off. Also, some of your ranges are not fully qualified which will cause problems if you change sheets while the code runs. Set whichever sheet you want this to operate on using `Set ws = Sheet1` - where Sheet1 is the codename or similar.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
Dim myfiles As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim temp_qt As QueryTable
Dim ws As Worksheet

myfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text files (*.txt), *.txt", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsEmpty(myfiles) Then
    Set ws = Sheet1
    For i = LBound(myfiles) To UBound(myfiles)

        Set temp_qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & myfiles(i), Destination:=ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))

         With temp_qt
            .Name = "Sample"
            .FieldNames = False
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i
    Set temp_qt = Nothing
    CleanUpQT
Else
MsgBox "No File Selected"
End If

End Sub

Sub CleanUpQT()
Dim connCount As Long
Dim i As Long

    connCount = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Count
    For i = 1 To connCount
        ThisWorkbook.Connections.Item(i).Delete
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed. I still get the same error! Any other idea? I have a total of 4500 txt files, which contain simple sentences (max. 200 characters).